# Laravel Eloquent: any way to update DB with dynamic fields?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to implement the "Edit Application Settings" feature. After a bit of thinking, my configuration values are stored in the DB with key -> value structure, like this:

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | logo_path | img/logo.png |

As you can see, for each setting, there is only a key & value column. I made an App Service provider to cache them forever, and a helper function (`config('setting_key')`) to get the value, but now I'd like to update it in the most efficient way.

The user interface consists of the `<form action="post" ...>` and input with a corresponding name, like this: `<input name="setting_key_name" ... />`. As you can see, the `name` attribute here has the value of the `key` column value and the actual value of the input would be the `value` column value (a bit of confusion here).

First thing that came to my mind, was to make a foreach loop and find & update every row in DB, but IMHO it is very unoptimized way, cause if the page has a form with 10 values, it is 10 SQL queries. But till now, this is what I've done:

```php
$keys = collect($request->except('_token'))->keys()->toArray();

// get all settings if the key name matches the request's input name
$setting = Setting::whereIn('key', $keys)->get();

$logo = self::GENERAL_APP_LOGO; // contant with a key-name (general_application_logo);

if($request->has(self::GENERAL_APP_LOGO) && $request->$logo) {
    // Processing uploaded image here;
    $this->uploadLogo($image, self::LOGO_IMAGE_PATH, $name); // Using an upload trait

    $setting->where('key', $logo)->value = self::LOGO_IMAGE_PATH . $name; // just a try to update the DB this way
}

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $setting->where('key', $key)->value = $request->$key; // putting all request's input values to corresponding key
}

$setting->save(); // saving the DB.
```

As you can see, this won't work and will throw an Exception, like `Call to undefined method ...\Eloquent\Builder::save()`. I tried the same code with an update, but the difficult part here is to update it multiple times (since the `if` section should have the update as well, for the logo), as well as binding the key to value.

So, a little bit of your help would be appreciated - what the logic should be here? How can I update a DB rows with corresponding column's value? I mean - like this `(update where key = 'general_app_name' set value, 'some_setting_value')`, but using the optimized and clear way?

### Working solution

As @miken32 stated in his answer, I used hid version of code, but with slight changes:

```
// Changed the $request->settings->keys() to PHP native method array_keys():
$settings = Settings::whereIn('key', array_keys($request->settings))->get()->groupBy('id');
// Also, here I changed the `whereIn('id', ...)` to `whereIn('key', ...)`, since it was my primary index.

foreach ($request->settings as $k=>$v) {
  if ($k === self::GENERAL_APP_LOGO_ID) {
    // not sure about this one, but I think this is
    // how you'd access a file input in an array
    $image = $request->file('settings')[$k];
    $this->uploadLogo($image, self::LOGO_IMAGE_PATH, $name);
    $v = self::LOGO_IMAGE_PATH . $name;
  }
  // take the Setting object out of the list we pulled
  // Here I added the ->first() to get the first element from the retrieved collection;
  $setting = $settings->get($k)->first();
  $setting->value = $v;
  $setting->save();
}
```

Since I was fetching the configuration values via helper, that only returns the value of the current key (and no `id` column), I changed the `id` to `key` and made the `key` as my PK in a model. Works like a charm!

Comment: If each Setting object is a different row in the database, you don't have any choice but to do a separate query to update each one. I will say that `$setting->where('key', $key)->value` won't work because `$setting->where('key', $key)` returns a collection. `$setting->where('key', $key)->first()->value` might work better.

Comment: @miken32 and no way to make it smoother and reduce the DB load? Like combine arrays or something - just can't think of the most suitable method right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each setting in a separate row, there's no way to avoid multiple database queries – one to get the current values for all settings, and other to update each one. Looking up items by primary key is more efficient, so I'd recommend putting the contents of the `id` column in your blade view, like this:

```html
<label for="setting_{{$setting->id}}">{{$setting->key}}</label>
<input name="settings[{{$setting->id}}]" id="setting_{{$setting->id}}" value="{{$setting->value}}"/>
```

Now in your controller, `$request->settings` will be an array you can loop through. You can continue treating your file upload separately, but now you've got the `id` column to look up, so change your constant to that.

```php
$settings = Settings::whereIn('id', $request->settings->keys())->get()->groupBy('id');

foreach ($request->settings as $k=>$v) {
    if ($k === self::GENERAL_APP_LOGO_ID) {
        // not sure about this one, but I think this is
        // how you'd access a file input in an array
        $image = $request->file('settings')[$k];
        $this->uploadLogo($image, self::LOGO_IMAGE_PATH, $name);
        $v = self::LOGO_IMAGE_PATH . $name;
    }
    // take the Setting object out of the list we pulled
    $setting = $settings->get($k);
    $setting->value = $v;
    $setting->save();
}
```

Note that Laravel does offer methods to bulk-update multiple models at once, but they are doing separate queries to the database in the background. IIRC, the `save()` method doesn't do anything if the value hasn't changed, which will spare you some hits.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply! I will try to implement this method. And, yeah - I didn't know that `->save()` does nothing if the value is unchanged.

Comment: Honestly doesn't seem like this should be anything to worry about; I can't imagine they get updated often enough to cause a performance concern, since the update is coming from a form.

Comment: Well, just a small update: I used your method, but made a bit changes in it. Firstly, I changed the `$request->settings->keys()` to `array_keys($request->settings)`, as well selected the first element from the given collection: `$setting = $settings->get($key)->first()`. Now it works good. The only problem I've got is that the logo won't upload to the server (I'm using wamp for dev env), but that's a story for another problem > solution. Thank again and have a nice day! :)

Comment: Please, kindly see the update in my question to see all changed in the code that I've done

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a text field, or a json field if your database supports it, and storing all of your settings as a JSON string in that field.

| id | settings |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { "logo_path" : "img/logo.png", "foo" : "bar", "thing_count" : 17 } |
| 2 | { "logo_path" : "img/logo2.png", "foo" : "baz", "thing_count" : 4 } |

In your Laravel model, you can cast it as an array

```
protected $casts = ["settings" => "array"];
```

and then use it from the model

```
echo $theModel->settings['logo'];
echo $theModel->settings['foo'];
```

or you can cast it as a fully fledged object if you need to using [value object casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#value-object-casting).

One gotcha that can be confusing for people is the setting of the values in the array to update it. This will not work:

```
$theModel->settings['foo'] = "boz";
```

The reason is due to the way the Laravel mutators work. Instead, you make a value copy of the settings, change that, and reassign it to the model:

```
$settings = $theModel->settings;
$settings['foo'] = "boz";
$theModel->settings = $settings;
```

This approach has the capacity to infinitely expandable in the future as you just add new keys to your json. Be sure to do checks on the settings array to ensure fields you are looking for are set (which is why value objects can be very handy to do validation).

It also solves your database query problem - it's only ever one.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I've been taught that storing a structured data in a RDBMS within a Laravel is a bad practice, despite I implement this method in my other project (that was actually a practice for myself, as this one is). It makes things like counting entries more difficult, as well as increases the Server load and response time (since serializing and putting data to JSON object is a separate procedure). That's why I was trying to avoid this way of implementation. It is okay if you put it in the No-SQL DB, like Elasticsearch and so on

Comment: Like most things, it depends on your use case, and how often you'll need perform these actions. The overhead in processing the JSON is miniscule vs the overhead on all the SQL queries, unless you have tens of thousands of keys in your settings. If you're having to count how many times a key appears, you can use json querying in some databases (or some other form of map reducing). It's going to be a tradeoff that you'll need work out for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to put

```
$setting->where('key', $logo)->value = ...;
```

Just call

```
$setting->where('key', $logo)->update($request->toArray());
```

$setting->save(); called when you instantiated setting class like :

```
$setting = new Setting();
```

Or

```
$setting = Setting::whereIn('key', $keys)->get()->first();
```

Then

```
$setting->val = ...;
$setting->save(); // then it work's
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well, let's say I'm doing the `$setting = Setting::whereIn('key', $keys)->get()->first();` and then `$setting->value = $request->$key`, it means that I'll have to put the query in foreach loop, right? As well as the first version: `$setting->where('key', $logo)->update($request->toArray());` - will it populate DB with all form data or once again - foreach it is?

Comment: `$setting->where('key', $logo)->update($request->toArray());` It will populate DB with all form data. But remember the update method will use Key Value as Column name and Value to update the table.